# Call a function inside a loop, but cannot return the results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, for-loop

I have a function, say `func(var)` which returns 3 dataframes according to the variable I input.

For example, if I write

```
df_a,df_b,df_c = func(7)
```

I will get three dataframes.

However, if I call the function inside a for loop, I could not get back the result.

For example,

```
for i in range(1,4):
    df_a_i, df_b_i, df_c_i = func(i)
```

I could not get back `df_a_1` or anything else.I get an error

```
NameError: name 'df_a_1' is not defined
```

etc.

If I try to call it manually, that is

```
df_a_1, df_b_1, df_c_1 = func(1)
df_a_2, df_b_2, df_c_2 = func(2)
df_a_3, df_b_3, df_c_3 = func(3)
df_a_4, df_b_4, df_c_4 = func(4)
```

which is completely fine.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you return a three arguments from func(), that it have to work:

```
def func(a):
    return a + 1, a + 2, a + 3

d = {}

for i in range(1, 4):
    df_a_i, df_b_i, df_c_i = func(i)
    d['df_a_%i' % i] = df_a_i
    d['df_b_%i' % i] = df_b_i
    d['df_c_%i' % i] = df_c_i

print(d['df_a_1'])
```

Comment: But how can I get the result outside the loop, like how can I get back df_a_1 outside the for-loop?

Comment: def func(a):
    return a + 1, a + 2, a + 3
d = {}
for i in range(5):
    df_a_i, df_b_i, df_c_i = func(i)
    d['df_a_%i' % i] = df_a_i
    d['df_b_%i' % i] = df_b_i
    d['df_c_%i' % i] = df_c_i

print(d['df_a_1'])

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using an extra array.

```
df_s = []
for i in range(1,4):
    df_a, df_b, df_c = func(i)
    df_s.append([df_a, df_b, df_c])

# get the ith df
df_s[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary for a variable number of variables. Don't try and name variables dynamically. This usually leads to unmanageable code. Here you can use a nested dictionary.

```
def func(i):
    return i, i+1, i+2

d = {i: {} for i in 'abc'}

for i in range(1, 4):
    d['a'][i], d['b'][i], d['c'][i] = func(i)

print(d)

{'a': {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3},
 'b': {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
 'c': {1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5}}
```

If you prefer, you can use tuple keys:

```
def func(i):
    return i, i+1, i+2

d = {}

for i in range(1, 4):
    d[('a', i)], d[('b', i)], d[('c', i)] = func(i)

print(d)

{('a', 1): 1, ('b', 1): 2, ('c', 1): 3,
 ('a', 2): 2, ('b', 2): 3, ('c', 2): 4,
 ('a', 3): 3, ('b', 3): 4, ('c', 3): 5}
```